# How to visualize 3 factors using geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 factors that I would like to represent on an NMDS plot.

my first attempt is this:
However, I would like the circles (or triangles) to be filled, or empty based on if they are Fungi or NF)

```
ggplot(data=NMDS2_plsMet,aes(x,y,colour=Location))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Insect,fill=Fungi))+theme_bw()
```

[image]

So then I tried this:

```
ggplot(data=NMDS2_plsMet,aes(x,y,colour=Location))+
 geom_point(aes(shape=Insect,fill=Fungi))+
 scale_shape_manual(values=shape_values)+theme_bw()
```

Any suggestions for how I can have filled/empty circles and triangles.

[image]

Comment: some of the shapes (21-25 I think) take a fill  as well as a colour.

Comment: You might need to use both `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_size_manual` (scale_size_manual will need both Insect and Fungi, and may be needed to select shapes that are hollow). For `scale_fill_manual`, try something akin to `+scale_fill_manual(name = "Type", labels = c("Fungi", "NF"), values = c())` http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually#change-colors-manually

Comment: thanks this helped